# Godot Area2D doesn't detect object in the right moment

Tags: c#, godot

I'm prototyping a snake game. The head is a kinematicbody2d, and the body is a Line2D with an Area2D attached to it with a ConvexPolygonShape2D as a collider. The polygon is generated using the offset_polyline_2d function with the Line2D vectore as an argument.
This is the scene tree:

[image]

For some reason, the body's Area2D's signal "body_entered" that has to detect the head doesn't fire in the right moments. It emits a signal at what seems to be "random moment" (but they are obviously not random...).

Does it have something to do with local/global positions? Aren't Area2D supposed to handle understanding the positions themselves?

Thank you

Comment: First things you could check? Did you run the Scene in debugger and displayed your collision shapes? (Debug Menu -> Visible Collision Shapes)

Then you would at least see, if your generated polygon works as you intented.

Comment: Generate a `Polygon2D` along side, so you can better see the result.